# Need help on a minimal module for prestashop 1.7.x

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to write a module for prestashop 1.7.x for the first time !
It would be nice if someone could give me a hint how to start up.
I would like to use a php function with smarty call like {$page.page_name|test}

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Hardy Thiergart and welcome to SO!

You can easily write your first PrestaShop module by following the tutorial here:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/

**Main steps:**

1. Create a folder with your module's name
2. Create a PHP file with the same name
3. Make sure your PHP file contains at least the __construct(), install(), uninstall() and getContent() methods (the last one is required only if you allow users to 'Configure' this module)
4. You can then add additional methods for Hooks, including calls to your template files
5. Once ready, create a zip file of this folder, with your module's name

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to generate an empty Prestashop module with hooks, etc ... : https://validator.prestashop.com/auth/login

Regards